# C++ MyInteger Class with Overload [ ] operator so index returns digit in position i

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

**The problem I have**

Define a class named MyInteger that stores an integer and has functions to get and set the intergers value. Then, overload the [] operator so that the index returns the digit in position i, where i = 0 is the least-significant digit. If no such digit exists then -1 should be returned.

I understand the first part but I don't understand how to implement the second part,

> Then, overload the [] operator so that the index returns the digit in position i, where i = 0 is the least-significant digit. If no such digit exists then -1 should be returned.

**My code is such:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyInteger{
private:
  int integer;
public:
  MyInteger(int bInteger = 0)
  {
     integer = bInteger;
  }
  int getInteger(){ return integer; }
  void setInteger(int bInteger){ integer = bInteger; }

  void operator[](int x) //???
  {
  }

};

int main()
{

  cout << "Enter an integer " << endl;
  //cin >> 

}
```

Comment: That operator must return `int` not `void`.

Comment: How many digits can `MyInteger` have?

Comment: I assume it doesn't matter how many integers there are. The instructions aren't really clear and my instructor can't even offer any help...

Comment: `int` can only represent values from -2147483648 to 2147483647, so that only supports 10 digits.  You may want to store values using another format if 10 digits isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand the second part you have to implement the operator to return a single digit. 
In a way that given

```
MyInteger x;
x.set(43210)
int a = x[0];
int b = x[1];
int c = x[5];
```

a should equal 0, b should equal 1 and c should equal -1. To get the digits you could use modulo arithmetic:

To get the first digit (index 0) of any integer "i" just return i%10. To get the second digit (index 1)

```
int result = ((i - (i%10)) % 100) / 100
```

for the 2nd index

```
int result = ((i - (i%10) - (i%100)) % 1000) / 1000
```

This may be formulated more elegently with a for loop.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks to all, between all the input, I'll try and put something together.

Answer (score 0):

For decimal number your class should return decimal digit corresponding to the position (index) e.g. if MyInteger m=12347 the operator m[0] would return 7, m[3] would return 2, and m[6] would return -1.

Answer (score 0):

For your first part of the question, I propose you the following:

```
int operator[](int x) 
{
    int ten; 
    for (ten = 10; x; x--)
        ten *= 10; 
    int digit = (integer%ten) / (ten / 10);
    return digit; 
}
```

By the way, to ease tests, I propose you to define the following to permit using cin on `MyInteger`:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, MyInteger& x) 
{
    int v; 
    is >> v;
    x.setInteger(v); 
    return is;
}
```

**For the second part**, *If no such digit exists then -1 should be returned.*, addresses the "out of bound" that you could have.  For example, if you'd have x = 21 and you'd do x[3], you'd return 0 with the programme above whereas in reality there is no fourth digit.

So you could change the last instruction of  `operator[]` as follows:

```
    return integer>=ten/10 ?  digit:-1;
```

Comment: I really wonder how you think the algorithm forsooth? It is really interesting

Answer (score 0):

I can share you my code.
But i not sure if it is best to solve your problem.

```css
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

class MyInteger
{
public:
 MyInteger(int integer);
 MyInteger();
 int operator[](int index);
 void set(int integer);
 int get();
private:
 int integer;
};
int main()
{
 MyInteger integer;

 integer.set(123456);
 cout<<"MyInteger: "<<integer.get()<<endl;
 int i;   /*position*/
 cout<<"Enter the reference from zero to fine digit>>";
 cin>>i;

 if(integer[i]==-1)
  cout<<"The integer doesn't exit.\n";
 else
     cout<<"The digit is: "<<integer[i];

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
MyInteger::MyInteger(int integer)
{
 this->integer=integer;
}
MyInteger::MyInteger()
{
 this->integer=0;
}
int MyInteger::operator[](int index)
{
 /*檢測是否在範圍內*/
 int size=0;
 int replacement=this->integer;
 do
 {
  replacement=replacement/10;
  size++;
 }while(replacement!=0);
 if(index>=size)
 {
  cout<<"It is not in range!\n";
   return -1;
 }
 
 /*找出位置上的digit*/
 int target=0;
 int head=pow(10.0,index+1);  /*去頭用*/
 target=(this->integer)-((this->integer)-(this->integer)%head);
 int foot=pow(10.0,index);    /*去尾用*/
 target=target/foot;
 
 
 return target;
}
void MyInteger::set(int integer)
{
 if((integer-(int)integer)==0)
  this->integer=integer;
 else
 {
  cout<<"It is not a intger!!";
  exit(1);
 }
}
int MyInteger::get()
{
    return this->integer;
}
```